# It's so long vs its been so long - What's the difference?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Does this make a difference in the meaning in the following sentence if `been` is included before so long?

Which one of it is correct?

> a).It's ***been*** so long since we had a meeting that I've forgotten.
>
> b) It's so long since we had a meeting that I've forgotten.

Comment: It's been = it has been.  It's so long = It is so long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the **'s** ends up having a completely different meaning in your two sentences:

> a) It's [it **has**] been so long since we had a meeting that I've forgotten.
>
> b) It's [it **is**] so long since we had a meeting that I've forgotten.

To my ears, option a) sounds better: you are using the [present perfect](https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect/) **has been** to express the ongoing situation that time has been progressing without any meetings since the last meeting you **had** (simple past).

Option b) is grammatical, but awkward, since you're using the simple present **is** to refer to a time period that extends into the past, and then combining with the simple past **had**.  Option a) is definitely the more natural-sounding choice.